# Why don't my prometheus labels show up?

Tags: go, prometheus

I'm trying to add labels to a metric in a push gateway. Here is the code I'm using:

```
completionTime := prometheus.NewGaugeVec(
        prometheus.GaugeOpts{
                Name: "completion_timestamp_seconds",
                Help: "The timestamp of the last successful completion.",
        },  
        []string{"cluster"},
)   
completionTime.With(prometheus.Labels{"cluster": cluster}).SetToCurrentTime()
if err := push.New(fmt.Sprintf(pushgatewayIngress, cluster), "job_completion_time").
        Collector(completionTime).
        Push(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Could not push completion time to Pushgateway:", err)
}
```

The metric is being updated, but it's not including the label. Do I need to add something to the `Collector`?

Answer (score 5):

Could you share your prometheus scrape configuration?

I made a minimal example based on yours and labels seem to be correctly updated on the prometheus side.

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus"
    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/push"
)

const (
    pushgatewayIngress = "http://localhost:9091"
    cluster            = "testCluster"
)

func main() {
    completionTime := prometheus.NewGaugeVec(
        prometheus.GaugeOpts{
            Name: "completion_timestamp_seconds",
            Help: "The timestamp of the last successful completion.",
        },
        []string{"cluster"},
    )
    completionTime.With(prometheus.Labels{"cluster": cluster}).SetToCurrentTime()
    if err := push.New(pushgatewayIngress, "job_completion_time").
        Collector(completionTime).
        Push(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Could not push completion time to Pushgateway:", err)
    }

    fmt.Println("done")
}
```

**prometheus.yml** - (configuration file)

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  evaluation_interval: 15s

scrape_configs:
- job_name: pushgateway
  scrape_interval: 5s
  static_configs:
    - targets: ['pushgateway:9091']
```

**docker-compose.yml** - sets up containers for pushgateway and prometheus in containers

```
pushgateway:
  image: prom/pushgateway
  ports:
    - 9091:9091

prometheus:
  image: prom/prometheus
  ports:
    - 9090:9090
  links:
    - pushgateway:pushgateway
  volumes:
    - ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
```

You run `docker-compose up` from the folder with docker-compose.yml and prometheus.yml, and this should work (it works on my side). Do you see any differences between this and your configuration?

Note, that you may want to use `honor_labels: true` in your scrape config for correct label collection, as described [here](https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway#about-the-job-and-instance-labels)

Comment: This turned out to be simply an inconsistency with the UI. The labels were there, I just had to click on the metric, whereas previously and with other metrics/labels, they were displayed next to the metric without having to drill down :facepalm: not sure why they require drilling down now.